# Angular v4.3.3: Is there an alternative to accessing template elements by template ID other than @ViewChild?

Tags: typescript, angular2-template

In earlier versions this was an acceptable way to grab an Element Reference using @ViewChild.

`@ViewChild('#templateId') elementName: ElementRef;`

From what it seems now this is no longer a viable option since @ViewChild is looking for a specific component to inject.

I have dabbled with injecting `ElementRef` into the constructor but the Element Reference I am trying to handle is deeply nested within the template. Maybe this is the best solution but I am searching for something better if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use the `@ViewChild` decorator to query an elment from the view template. For example:

```
@ViewChild('templateId')
public myElement: ElementRef<any>;
```

...

```
<div #templateId></div>
```

Will get the ElementRef of the `div` with `#templateId`. But keep in mind that only one element with `#templateId` should exist to query it via `ViewChild`. And it's  only available after the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle-hook.

Comment: Perfect. I must have been adding the hash (#) inside the ViewChild. I am glad I was wrong.